# Can i make conditional binding in kendo ui

Tags: kendo-ui

I need is to apply binding to a section of markup to appear in my document (and to have its data-bind attributes applied), only if a specified expression evaluates to true.
I tried to implement it using slideUp/slideDown and visible binding. The difference is that, with slideUp/slideDown, the contained markup always remains in the DOM and always has its data-bind attributes applied - the visible binding just uses CSS to toggle the container element’s visibility. I suppose that I need physically adds or removes the contained markup in my DOM, and only applies bindings to descendants if the expression is true. Could anyone propose please good approach for this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I understood you would like to modify the HTML with a binding. To achieve that you may use the HTML binding. As an example:

```
<div id="example">
    <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: value"/>
    <div id="wrapper" data-bind="html: setHTML"></div>
    <br />
    value: <span data-bind="text: value"></span>
</div>

var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    value: false,
    name: "Jack",
    setHTML: function (e) {
        var flag = this.get("value"),
            html;
        if(flag) { //include the html
            html = '<input id="name" data-bind="value: name" />';
            return html;
        } else { //remove the html
            return "";
        }
    }
});
kendo.bind($("#example"), viewModel);
```

Note that the inserted HTML elements will not be bound to the View-Model. To achieve that you should call kendo.bind manually.

```
kendo.bind($("#wrapper"), viewModel);
```

I hope this will solution will fit in your scenario.